# String reversal in Python

Tags: python

I have taken an integer input and tried to reverse it in Python but in vain! I changed it into a string but still I am not able to. Is there any way to reverse it ? Is there any built-in function?

I am not able to convert the integer into a list so not able to apply the reverse function.

Comment: This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python/931095#931095

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the slicing operator to reverse a string:

```
s = "hello, world"
s = s[::-1]
print s  # prints "dlrow ,olleh"
```

To convert an integer to a string, reverse it, and convert it back to an integer, you can do:

```
x = 314159
x = int(str(x)[::-1])
print x  # prints 951413
```

Comment: renamed str -> s to avoid confusion with builtin str

Answer (score 4):

Code:

```
>>> n = 1234
>>> print str(n)[::-1]
4321
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> int(''.join(reversed(str(12345))))
54321
```

Comment: Note: Not as pythonic as the slicing operator solution.